# ERROR in python sql code : 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'z' in 'field list'

Tags: python, sql, database

Everytime i execute my program, i get this error : 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'z' in 'field list'.

Here's a snippet of the code, it shows error in :

```
mycursor.execute("insert into signup values("+username+","+password+");")
```

here's snippet of the code where it goes wrong:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

import mysql.connector

mydatabase = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="xxx"
)

mycursor=mydatabase.cursor()

mycursor.execute("create database if not exists aisha")
mycursor.execute("use aisha")
mycursor.execute("create table if not exists signup(username varchar(30),password varchar(30))")

def signup():
    username=input('USERNAME:')
    password=input("PASSWORD:")
    mycursor.execute("insert into signup values("+username+","+password+");")
    mydatabase.commit()
    print("\t\t\t****SIGNUP SUCESSFUL***")
    print("Now please login to continue.")
    login()
```

the output is:

```
                        ---- BANK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM----
Welcome! To sign up, enter 1 ; To login in, enter 2
 (1/2)?: 1
USERNAME:z
PASSWORD:1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put single quotes around `username` and `password`:

```py
    mycursor.execute("insert into signup values('"+username+"','"+password+"');")
```

Then the string passed to `execute` becomes:

```py
    mycursor.execute("Insert into signup values('Z','1');")
```

instead of:

```py
    mycursor.execute("Insert into signup values(Z,1);")
```

But much better is to use instead a prepared statement, which also avoids a possible [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack:

```py
    mycursor.execute("Insert into signup values(%s,%s);", (username, password))
```

Comment: Did this answer your question to your satisfaction?